# Computationally efficient C++ - general reading

Tags: c++, performance, optimization

My job is mainly in high-performance 'scientific' computing. I've been doing that for ~15 years now, but only recently realized that my software wastes computational time. In short words: **my ways of writing efficient C++ code no longer work.**

From time to time I see a piece of code, written by some kid, that does basically the same calculations as mine (same algorithm, similar approach), but - magically! - performs far faster. In most cases I'm even unable of tracking down the origins of the difference!

My question is: **how can I learn the art of modern C++ code optimization?** Perhaps something on SSE, caching/mem alignment issues? Any suggestion of book, PDF, article, exercise or website is welcome!

PS. I'm well aware of tricks that are either:

- Too general (e.g. 'Use profiler', 'Use good algorithms', 'Go multithreaded')
- Trivial (e.g. 'Avoid virtual functions', 'Do ++i instead of i++', 'Enable -O3')
- Questionable (e.g. 'Reuse memory with reinterpret_cast<>', 'Tabularize sine and cosine', 'Write inline assembly')
- Ridiculous (e.g. 'Do template metaprogramming')

These are **not** what I'm asking about.

Comment: A good book IMO: http://www.intel.com/intelpress/sum_swcb2.htm

Comment: From what I've seen up until now, I'd say avoid dynamic memory allocation when possible and pack your data intelligently rather than randomly. In general application memory is the bottleneck (well, apart from disk/network IOs...). Also, in MT situations, false sharing is a killer now that we have true multi-core/multi-processors environments; bit harder to diagnose too. However, no idea how this applies to scientific computing.

Comment: *"time to time ... a piece of code, ... does basically the same calculations as mine ... but - magically! - performs far faster. "* - Post your few examples that you have (possibly in different question). I'm sure people here will be able to find out how the difference comes about.

Comment: *"... unable of tracking down the origins of the difference!"* - This, IMHO, no offense intended, suggests that you are not up do speed with your debugging/profiling tools.

Comment: It is ridiculous to assume that template metaprogramming is generally ridiculous. Especially when the proclaimer claims to have a scientific background and calls those who are up to date "kids". Maybe you have become rusty or even lazy instead?

Comment: @Martin: I somewhat agree, but it still can be difficult to actually *understand* where the difference comes from. With O3, functions get inlined, loops unrolled and rearranged, etc... so understanding why the *C++* code changes produced those effects can be daunting.

Comment: If you don't show us samples of both your slow code and the new fast code, then we won't know what the problem is.

Comment: @Martin I cannot post the code for many reasons. In praticular, this is not a question about the case where single function needs to be optimized without the understanding of whole context. This is about the art ;)

Comment: If you think that template metaprogramming is “ridiculous” then I can say right there that *this* is your problem, and the origin of the observed differences.

Comment: @phresnel Honestly, I've never encountered a real-life problem addressed by template metaprogramming (why not use precomputing or loop unrolling then?). Anyway, you're right, I stopped learning at some point... perhaps it was the point when I got married.

Comment: @user1225822: Because e.g. [expression templates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expression_templates) (first mentioned 1995) do all the unrolling and vectorization for you already, without sacrificing any maintainability. A real life, scientific example for their use are spectral computations. Templates are actually only seldom used to pre-compute data (even though it is possible, see my http://gitorious.org/metatrace), but rather to compute programs; that's why we talk about metaprogramming.

Comment: I recommend reading basically everything written by Agner Fog, starting with http://www.agner.org/optimize/optimizing_cpp.pdf

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I too work in scientific computation though for rather longer than OP and mainly in Fortran.  here's a little advice from my experience;

1) Keep up to date with what compiler(s) can do.  On the one hand don't try to beat the compiler at optimisation tricks that the compiler knows about, on the other, know what compilers still aren't good at. For example, right now I think I can do a better job than my compiler at loop tiling. Learn too how to make it easy for the compiler to optimise code.

OP will be tempted to pass this point off as an example of advice which is too general to be of use. I see that the Intel C++ compiler manual has about 800 pages of documentation of the compiler options, and a further 400 on optimizing applications.  Has OP read all this (or similar quantity of documentation for preferred compiler) ?

2) Keep up to date with computer architecture, in particular with the design of the memory hierarchy and of the fpus.  If nothing else, this helps to understand what the limits of performance one can reasonable expect might be. But it also provides input to decisions on program design and implementation, and indications of how those decisions ought to change when programs are moved to the next generation of hardware.

3) Use libraries.  Write code as a last resort.

4) Don't pooh-pooh ideas such as template metaprogramming which have a very good reputation for helping the programmer to create fast code.  Study Boost and Blitz.

5) Program performance is an empirical discipline.  Believe only data, not argument.  Not even argument made by me.

Finally, even in large-scale high-performance computing (my largest jobs run for days on 10K CPUs and more so I have a little knowledge of this), sometimes the activity to optimise is development time, not execution time.

PS Did you ask the kid for instruction ?

Answer (score 6):

Processors are much faster than they were 15 years ago. Memory has not incrased in speed at the same rate. This combined with larger data sets, particularly in big scientific simulations, means you have to think a bit more carefully about how the data is accessed. That is maybe one of the differences.

I found these articles interesting:

http://overbyte.com.au/2011/10/21/optimisationmasterclass1/

http://overbyte.com.au/2011/11/10/optimisation-lesson-2/

They are written by a guy I know who wrote games engines and who now optimizes PS3 games. You might find them useful.

Answer (score 3):

I can not call this guy a "kid", but you may find useful this course:   [Advanced STL](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Going+Deep/C9-Lectures-Stephan-T-Lavavej-Advanced-STL-1-of-n)
from MSDN Channel9 Lectures of Stephan T Lavavej (VC++ team member and maintainer of STL there). The quality of the video, though, is not good on my side. Probably, you will be more lucky.

Answer (score 3):

The book "Computer architecture- a quantitative approach" hennessey and patterson. Not specifically targeting C++ but even more important the overall architecture. This is crucial for HPC even more than any "trick and tips".

Answer (score 2):

Log time ago I readed two books that helped me:

1. Efficient C++ Performance Programing Techniques by Bulka & Meyhew
2. More effective C++

Besides, visit [BrDobbs](http://drdobbs.com/cpp/) periodically and, of course, stackoverflow !!!

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget grid processing. Long calculations can be performed across multiple CPUs or multiple threads.

That is one modern way to improve calculation time.

The others tend to be the standard ones:
- efficient use of caching
- efficient use of lazy evaluation

and avoiding locking/unlocking whilst doing all this.